# Bug in FlowDocument Table?

Tags: c#, wpf, flowdocument

first of all, Width calculation of FlowDocuments TableColumns is a mess. but this is rather ridiculous:

```xml
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
    <FlowDocument>
     <Paragraph>text that's not visible</Paragraph>
     <Table BorderThickness="0.7559" >
        <Table.Columns>
         <TableColumn Width="100" />
        </Table.Columns>
        <TableRowGroup>
         <TableRow>
            <TableCell/>
         </TableRow>
        </TableRowGroup>
     </Table>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

this actually shows nothing. So the table seems to mess up the whole document. If I either take out the `Width="100"` or change the Borderthickness to something less precise like `BorderThickness="0.755"` it does show the table and Paragraph as expected. (Trying things out with this code even crashes Kaxaml.)

This is a very stripped down solution. My real FlowDocument gets calculated based on other data so it's not like I could just use a different value based on visual inspection.

**Can someone tell me what is happening here? And how I can solve this issue?**

**EDIT:**

[As suggested I added a bug report.](https://connect.microsoft.com/WPF/feedback/details/666624/flowdocument-borderthickness-and-columnwidth)

Comment: Crashing Kaxaml is not that hard though; good question...

Comment: Maybe you should send a bug report if you haven't already.

Comment: @H.B. have you tried the code and can reproduce the bug?

Comment: Yes i can, pasted it into Kaxaml earlier.

Comment: I can also reproduce this problem.  There must be some bug in how the math is performed.  0.7559 causes a problem.  0.755 works.  0.759 causes a problem.  4.7559 causes a problem.  Maybe a rounding issue?  A bad matrix transform?  There is really nothing you can do to fix the issue.  The ball is in Microsoft's court.  I helped to promote your bug on Connect.

Comment: @Scott thanks. How were you able to _a)_ identify it being an ExecutionEngineException and _b)_ find that it appears to be failing an assert? I'm asking because currently I was working around the issue by manually rounding to less precision, but while you state that 0.759 also does not work I might have to rethink my current 'solution'.

Comment: Glad to help.  It is a strange error.  I was surprised to find it is deep framework bug.  What I did: a) created a new .Net 4 project using VS2010.  Copied your code verbatim and ran the project.  The IDE told me a FatalExecutionEngineError was detected.  b) Clicked 'OK' to the message box.  Inspected the stack for the Main thread.  You can see the call to MS.Internal.Invaraint.Asset from the internal FlowDocumentPaginator.