# FlowDocument TableColumn Width with star notation doesn't work consistently?

Tags: wpf, flowdocument

Can anyone explain why these two documents show differently?

Good one:

```
<FlowDocument>
  <Table>
    <Table.Columns>
      <TableColumn Width="1*" />
      <TableColumn Width="2*" />
    </Table.Columns>
    <TableRowGroup>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>
            <Run>Name</Run>
          </Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>
            <Run>Address</Run>
          </Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableRowGroup>
  </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```

Bad one:

```
<FlowDocument>
  <Table>
    <Table.Columns>
      <TableColumn Width="1000*" />
      <TableColumn Width="2000*" />
    </Table.Columns>
    <TableRowGroup>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>
            <Run>Name</Run>
          </Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>
            <Run>Address</Run>
          </Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableRowGroup>
  </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```

The only difference is the multiplier of the star. Is this a bug?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, question being where the other question is... **Edit:** I confused it with [another bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868332/bug-in-flowdocument-table).

Comment: Why do you need to split the screen in 3000?  The only time you would use this is to set one column to be 1/3000 which is one pixel even on a high resolution screen.

Comment: Eight years later and I'm wondering the same thing. What did you find? Is it a bug?

Comment: @paparazzo I know it's been eight years so feel free to ignore this comment, but for posterity this issue crops up with numbers less than 3000. I'm encountering it with total stars > 100